# Filter multiple lists BUT not all?

Tags: javascript, jquery

See the following code:

```
<input type="text" />

<h3>Category 1</h3>
<ul id="category1">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
</ul>

<h3>Category 2</h3>
<ul>
    <li>item27</li>
    <li>item28</li>
</ul>

<h3>Category 3</h3>
<ul>
    <li>item132</li>
    <li>item437</li>
</ul>
```

This is the JS

```
$(function(){

    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){

        var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $('ul li').each(function(){

             if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) == -1)
                 $(this).hide();
             else
                $(this).show();

        });     
    });

});
```

This will filter the lists BUT my question is how can I have it filter the Category 1 & 2 lists BUT NOT the Category 3 list. I want the category 3 list to stay in tact as the other lists are filtered down. Thank you in advance for any advice or guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If you give an `id` to the third `ul`, then you can exclude it using the [`:not()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/av4m3xqp/)

```
$('ul:not(#category3) li').each(function() {
  // ...
});
```

If you have to exclude multiple element, it would probably be better to just exclude a specific class.

In this case, the class `.exclude` was added to the third `ul` element:

```
$('ul:not(.exclude) li').each(function() {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you - answered solved in less than one minute,

Answer (score 1):

Try using `:lt()` selector with parameter `3` to return `li` elements having index less than `3`

```
$("ul li:lt(3)")
```

```js
$(function(){

    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){

        var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $('ul li:lt(3)').each(function(){

             if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) == -1)
                 $(this).hide();
             else
                $(this).show();

        });     
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />

<h3>Category 1</h3>
<ul id="category1">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
</ul>

<h3>Category 2</h3>
<ul>
    <li>item27</li>
    <li>item28</li>
</ul>

<h3>Category 3</h3>
<ul>
    <li>item132</li>
    <li>item437</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip anything under category 3, you can do

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
//          the li...the ul...the h3
var header=$(this)  .parent().prev().text();
if (header==="Category 3"){
return true; //return true is like `continue` in an each block
}
//...rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Used some jQuery selector magic here: `$('ul').not(':last-child').children('li');` which grabs all `ul` elements, removes the last `ul` from the selected set, and then gets the children.

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
    var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var lis = $('ul').not(':last-child').children('li');
    lis.each(function(){
        var contents = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        $(this).toggle(contents.indexOf(text) >= 0);
    });     
});
```